# LBFGS wrapper in RcppNumerical

Tags: c++, rcpp, numerical-methods, rcpparmadillo, rcppeigen

I wrote a function to numerically find the quantiles of the following finite mixture of normals
[image]

In order to do that I am minimizing [image]. I am using the wrapper of `LBFGS` from `RcppNumerical` for the optimization problem. My code is like the following

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppGSL.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_math.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp17)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppNumerical)]]
#include <RcppNumerical.h>

using namespace Numer;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double log_sum_exp(const   arma::vec &x) {
  double maxVal= x.max();
  
  double sum_exp=sum(exp(x-maxVal));
  return log(sum_exp)+maxVal ;
}

class mixture_quantile: public MFuncGrad
{
private:
  const double a;
  const arma::vec mu, sd, pi;
public:
  mixture_quantile( const double &a_,const arma::vec & mu_, const arma::vec &sd_, const arma::vec &pi_) : a(a_), mu(mu_), sd(sd_), pi(pi_) {}
  
  double f_grad(Constvec&  x0, Refvec grad)
  {
    double x=x0[0];
    
    arma::vec std_x=(x-mu)/sd, log_pi=log(pi);
    
    arma::vec  log_norm_cdf=std_x ;
    log_norm_cdf.transform( [](double val) { return R::pnorm5(val,0,1,1,1); } );
    
    log_norm_cdf+=log_pi;
    
    double log_mixture_cdf=log_sum_exp(log_norm_cdf);
    
    double root_f=log_mixture_cdf-log(a);
    const double f= gsl_pow_2(root_f ); //function to return
    
    
    //derivative
    arma::vec wh= -.5*(square(std_x) +M_LNPI +M_LN2 ) -log(sd) + log_pi -log_mixture_cdf; 
    
    grad[0]= 2*root_f * exp(log_sum_exp(wh));
    return f;
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat gauss_solve_mat(const arma::vec &mu,const  arma::vec &sd,const arma::vec &pi,  
                          unsigned d, unsigned nthr=1)
{
  const unsigned nmix=mu.n_elem, n=100;
  mat mumat(d,nmix), sdmat(d,nmix), pimat(d,nmix);
  mumat.each_col()=mu,  sdmat.each_col()=sd, pimat.each_col()=sd;
  
  mat a(n,d,fill::randu );
  mat result(size(a));
  
  // #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthr)
  for(unsigned j = 0; j < d; ++j){
    vec tmpvec=a.col(j);
    
    
    for(unsigned i=0;i<n;++i){
      // Initial guess
      double fopt;
      mixture_quantile f(a(i,j),mumat.col(j),sdmat.col(j),pimat.col(j));
      // mixture_quantile f(a(i,j),mu,sd,pi);
      
      Eigen::VectorXd guess(1);
      
      guess[0]=0.;
      int res = optim_lbfgs(f, guess, fopt);
      cout<<"i="<<i<<" j="<<j<<endl;
      if(res < 0)
        cout<<"fail to converge. fopt= "<<fopt<<endl;
      // Rcpp::stop("fail to converge");
      tmpvec(i)=guess[0];
    }
    result.col(j)=tmpvec;
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

I know that the above script can be simplified but using this in order to generate a minimally reproducible code. I need to repeatedly use the numerical solver over matrices.

I saved this in the file `root_finding.cpp`. Now I prepared the following `R` script

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("root_finding.cpp")
mu=c(11.7669  , 11.2504 ,  11.6544  , 11.3683 ,  11.5435  , 13.1097  ,  1.1653  , 11.6884 ,  10.2279 ,  14.3162)
sd =c(0.3040 , 0.2813  , 0.2953 ,  0.3056 ,  0.2825  , 0.2853  , 0.2775  , 0.3007  , 0.2980   ,0.2816)
pi =c(0.0451 ,  0.1389 ,  0.1883 ,  0.1031 ,  0.0666 ,  0.1938 ,  0.0011 ,  0.2541 ,  0.0042 ,  0.0050)

gauss_solve_mat(mu,sd,pi,d=100,   nthr=1)
```

Whenever I run the above `R` script, I get the following error and the code crashes

```
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'RcppGSL':
  method               from         
  predict.fastLm       RcppArmadillo
  print.fastLm         RcppArmadillo
  summary.fastLm       RcppArmadillo
  print.summary.fastLm RcppArmadillo
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'RcppEigen':
  method               from   
  predict.fastLm       RcppGSL
  print.fastLm         RcppGSL
  summary.fastLm       RcppGSL
  print.summary.fastLm RcppGSL
using C++ compiler: ‘g++-13 (Homebrew GCC 13.1.0) 13.1.0’
using C++17
using SDK: ‘MacOSX13.3.sdk’
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib'
R(42451,0x1dc661e00) malloc: *** error for object 0x16d928e40: pointer being freed was not allocated
R(42451,0x1dc661e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      Rscript gauss_solve_vec.R
```

However the same functor `mixture_quantile` perfectly works in the following case when I use the minimizer function for a single alpha:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List gauss_solve(const arma::vec &mu,const  arma::vec &sd,const arma::vec &pi, const double a, double init)
{
  mixture_quantile nll(a,mu,sd,pi);
  double fopt;
  mixture_quantile f(a,mu,sd,pi);
  
  Eigen::VectorXd guess(1);
  
  int res = optim_lbfgs(f, guess, fopt);
  
  if(res < 0)
    Rcpp::stop("fail to converge");
  
  return Rcpp::List::create(
    Rcpp::Named("xopt") = guess[0],
    Rcpp::Named("fopt") = fopt,
    Rcpp::Named("status") = res
  );
}
```

**Output**

```
> mu=c(11.7669  , 11.2504 ,  11.6544  , 11.3683 ,  11.5435  , 13.1097  ,  1.1653  , 11.6884 ,  10.2279 ,  14.3162)
> sd =c(0.3040 , 0.2813  , 0.2953 ,  0.3056 ,  0.2825  , 0.2853  , 0.2775  , 0.3007  , 0.2980   ,0.2816)
> pi =c(0.0451 ,  0.1389 ,  0.1883 ,  0.1031 ,  0.0666 ,  0.1938 ,  0.0011 ,  0.2541 ,  0.0042 ,  0.0050)
> 
> a=0.000229046
> gauss_solve(mu,sd,pi,a,8)
$xopt
[1] 0.9398029

$fopt
[1] 7.340254e-12

$status
[1] 0
```

1. Can you help me with the issue in the first program?
2. If I need to multithread the code over `j` does simply uncommenting `// #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthr)` in `gauss_solve_mat` function work?

Comment: I have seen such segfaults at startup when one of the (compiled) R packages was out of sync in some way via its binary.  Can you show us your repository so that I can try on my Linux machine?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Sorry I didn't get your question. Can you please specify what do you need exactly? I have not uploaded this code to my GitHub repo yet.

Comment: I stated that I suspect your toolchain is broken and offered to run it locally if only you made the example reproducible by providing the code.  As you should anyway, really.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have provided both the `.cpp` file and the `R` script that compiles the `cpp` with `sourceCpp`. The scripts can be ran directly. Is there any issue in that?

Comment: No I must have missed that because your post was apparently longer, more detailed and whatnot that my bird brain attention span can support.  But I am not a fan of complex setups via `sourceCpp()` ; packages offer more control and checks.  But that may well be unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected (in comments above), no segfault here but a mere run-time error on mismatched dims:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/76593467/question.cpp")
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'RcppGSL':
  method               from         
  predict.fastLm       RcppArmadillo
  print.fastLm         RcppArmadillo
  summary.fastLm       RcppArmadillo
  print.summary.fastLm RcppArmadillo
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'RcppEigen':
  method               from   
  predict.fastLm       RcppGSL
  print.fastLm         RcppGSL
  summary.fastLm       RcppGSL
  print.summary.fastLm RcppGSL

> mu <- c(11.7669  , 11.2504 ,  11.6544  , 11.3683 ,  11.5435  , 13.1097  ,  1.1653  , 11.6884 ,  10.2279 ,  14.3162)

> sd <- c(0.3040 , 0.2813  , 0.2953 ,  0.3056 ,  0.2825  , 0.2853  , 0.2775  , 0.3007  , 0.2980   ,0.2816)

> pi <- c(0.0451 ,  0.1389 ,  0.1883 ,  0.1031 ,  0.0666 ,  0.1938 ,  0.0011 ,  0.2541 ,  0.0042 ,  0.0050)

> gauss_solve_mat(mu,sd,pi,d=100,   nthr=1)
Error in eval(ei, envir) : 
  each_col(): incompatible size; expected 100x1, got 10x1
>
```

(I appended your test to the cpp file with the usual `/*** R .... */` bracketing meaning that `sourceCpp()` will run as R code following the compilation.  See the Rcpp Attributes vignette, Section 1.5, for more.)

*Edit:*  If I correct `d=100` to `d=10` in the call, and comment out the per-iteration print, then things improve to this (where I also wrap the call in `str()` as the return is large:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/76593467/question.cpp")

> mu <- c(11.7669  , 11.2504 ,  11.6544  , 11.3683 ,  11.5435  , 13.1097  ,  1.1653  , 11.6884 ,  10.2279 ,  14.3162)

> sd <- c(0.3040 , 0.2813  , 0.2953 ,  0.3056 ,  0.2825  , 0.2853  , 0.2775  , 0.3007  , 0.2980   ,0.2816)

> pi <- c(0.0451 ,  0.1389 ,  0.1883 ,  0.1031 ,  0.0666 ,  0.1938 ,  0.0011 ,  0.2541 ,  0.0042 ,  0.0050)

> str(gauss_solve_mat(mu,sd,pi,d=10,   nthr=1))
 num [1:100, 1:10] 2.54 2.47 2.48 1.36 2.55 ...
>
```